# CSS float under and left

Tags: css, layout

I have many divs with variable height. I need these divs sort under each other but when they will reach end of window –> create new "column".

[image: Do not overflow but create new "column"]

Now divs are overflowing, but I need to create new "column".

BTW:

I have solution using:

```
-webkit-column-gap: 16px;
-webkit-column-width: 230px;
```

But I need to support other browsers.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: [The column api is supportert by al modern browers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn). And you can use a [polyfill](http://github.com/BetleyWhitehome/CSS3MultiColumn) for old browsers.

Comment: This is not possible with "normal" CSS, afaik you cannot control the vertical  overflow in that way. Horizontally it would be possible though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with **CSS only**,

an option would be using `column-count` and a `max-height` on the container.

see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yHTR/1)

but I am not sure about browser sopport.

It kinda does what you want, at least to some extend, but you would probably be better of with something in javascript.

**EDIT:** here I paste the CSS:

```
.container {
    column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    -ms-column-count: 3; 
    -o-column-count: 3;

    vertical-align:text-top;

    max-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin! If you are interested, I elaborated the answer a bit more in [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16560470/2113185) (for example how to make it so that the elemnts don't wrap between columns and how to use it in a more responsive way). Hope you find it useful, and if you want I can extend this answer with more examples aswel. Best! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The another way to solve this issue is using jQuery to get available window height and create each column based in this information. In other way, but still using jQuery, is you use Mansory jQuery (http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin or Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Where maxHeight is exactly equal to height of the window.

```
<style type="text/css">
.maxHeight {
  display:inline-table;
  height:600px;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  background-color:#09F;
  margin:3px;
}
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#33F;
  margin:2px;
}
</style>


<span class="maxHeight">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
</span>

<span class="maxHeight">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
</span>

<span class="maxHeight">
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
  <span class="box"></span>
</span>
```

The Javascript to loop through this will require a bit of attention but it is plenty possible.