# Layout divs in rows then columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container `div` and 3 `div` inside it as following.

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

I don't know about content of each `div` inside, but they have variable height and width.

Height of container is decided by tallest `div` inside.

I want to show these `div` such a way that they fill height first (left to right) and then move to next column like below.

```
+------------------+
|+-------++-------+|
||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||
|+-------+|       ||
|+-------+|       ||
||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||
|+-------+|       ||
|         +-------+|
+------------------+
```

Obviously if these `div`s are all big and can't fit in one column, the layout will be 3 columns like below

```
+---------------------------+
|+-------++-------++-------+|
||       ||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||       ||
||       ||       ||       ||
||       |+-------+|       ||
||       |         |       ||
|+-------+         |       ||
|                  +-------+|
+---------------------------+
```

**Question:** Is it possible to do this preferably using CSS only and how?

**EDIT**:

- There are few things that I need to clarify
- The container can have 2 or 3 columns at most (never 1 column and never more than 3).
- Width of the container is not fixed but with of all internal div are same.
- Height of container is decided by tallest internal div. for example if the tallest div is 300px height of container will be also be 300px.
- the other two shorter div should decide if they can fit in one column or should show in two separate columns. based on example (previous item).
- The other two smallest div should decide to be in one column or two columns.
- none of internal div should be wrapped.

**Example**:  div Heights: 1st 300px, 2nd 100px, 3rd 150px
  Result:   This is a 2 column layout (2nd and 3rd in same column).

**Example**:  div Heights: 1st 100px, 2nd 300px, 3rd 150px
Result:   This is a 3 column layout.

**Example**:  div Heights: 1st 100px, 2nd 200px, 3rd 300px
Result:   This is a 2 column layout (1st and 2nd in same column).

**Example**:  div Heights: 1st 100px, 2nd 210px, 3rd 300px
Result:   This is a 3 column layout.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is a complete fit for what you need but you may find it usefull: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: please create a fiddle i can't understand what you want? am confused

Comment: I was reading about this boxflex stuff recently. I haven't delved into it yet but it seems like a good solution for layout situations like the one you describe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Answer (score 1):

An **CSS only** solution to columns could be to use `column-count` and a `max-height` on the container (the wrapping `div`).

- see this answer: [CSS float under and left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332113/css-float-under-and-left/16561134#16561134)
- and a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5yHTR/1/) of a CSS-only approach

It kinda does what you want, at least to some extend. But it might break the `divs` at column breaks. So I think, you would probably be better of with something in javascript.

### Update:

After your **additional conditions**, I would add only this to my answer, concerning the CSS-only approach: `column-break-inside:avoid`. It still ain't perfect - but a bit closer to what you want. *You have to assign the `width` to columns, the divs can then be set to `width:100%`, the number of columns is automatic, alright, but I am not sure if you can dynamicaly adjust the container's width to the number of columns.*

**another note:** to avoid splitting the divs in firefox, you need to use `display:inline-block;` in addition.

So, here you can see how it performs with your examples: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yHTR/8/)

At least something to play with and maybe use another time ;-)

Comment: I fixed the last demo a little. And in addition, here I just wanted to add a slightly different version with your examples, illustrating how you could in quite an elegant way use this approach to implement a responsive design (if you try resizing the width): [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5yHTR/9/) I am not sure if you will find this useful. But it adds value to the approach ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The key is to make first two divs `display:inline-block` and last one `float:right`. Like this:

```
.container{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 200px; height: auto;
    margin: 20px; padding: 10px;
}
.container .one{
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container .two{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
.container .three{
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: right;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="three" style="width: 60px; height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="one" style="width: 60px; height: 80px;"></div>
    <div class="two" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="three" style="width: 70px; height: 100px;"></div>
    <div class="one" style="width: 70px; height: 80px;"></div>
    <div class="two" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is link to working result: http://jsfiddle.net/8xmrL/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question to clarify a few things

Comment: @BobSort I guess clarified question answer is no. This is impossible without of javascript.