# Display Divs one below the other

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div which is `100% width and 500px height`.

Now I want to put multiple `div`s of same size `width:250px; height:80px` one below the other and once it crosses the height of the parent div it should start to the right of the current column of `div`s.

Comment: Show some code what u tried till now?

Comment: @NoobEditor Start from `Now I want to put ...`

Comment: actually I wanted to add an image to explain my question but i'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: @HashemQolami : do you see any `problem` mentioned by OP as to why he is stucked??? :)

Comment: I don't think you can do this without some programming. You'd need to float new container divs against the previous one every time you get through 6 child divs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS float under and left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332113/css-float-under-and-left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CSS column layout. Something like this:

```
#parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: #eee;

    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
#parent .box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #AAA;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J8A24/

**Support**: [browser support chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn).
**Further reading**: [Multiple Columns](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/)

For IE you may want to use one of the many polyfills or leave it as is, inline-blocks will gracefully degrade for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Achievable with some PHP (untested):

```
<div style="width:100%;height:500px;position:relative;">
  <div class="innerContainer" style="float:left;width:250px;">
    <div class="innerDiv" style="height:80px;">
      <?php for($i = 1; $i < $numDivs; $i++) : ?>
        <?php if($i % 6 == 0) : ?>
          <!-- create new container div -->
          </div>
          <div class="innerContainer" style="float:left;width:250px;">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- put stuff in child div here -->
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use CSS columns as mentioned in the other answer, but I'm used to dealing with things that have to be widely supported in old browsers.