# Bootstrap grid - columns first?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I'm fairly new to Bootstrap and have come across a problematic task that I first thought would be pretty simple. And maybe it is for someone with sufficient experience of Bootstrap.

If I have a row of 12 columns that should be stacked on top of each other in a single-column layout, divided into 2 x 6 in a two-column layout and 3 x 4 in a three-column layout, the result would typically be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

and

```
1    2
3    4
5    6
7    8
9    10
11   12
```

and

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
10   11   12
```

What I want, however, is this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

and

```
1    7
2    8
3    9
4    10
5    11
6    12
```

and

```
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    11
4    8    12
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this with standard Bootstrap classes?

There is an example of such a layout here: http://bildarkivet.orsa.se At this site the 12 input elements are ordered into columns with the CSS column-count property, but it would be nice to be able to incorporate a similar ordering style into a Bootstrap-based site.

Comment: I believe without JS, it's possible with a mixture of `-hidden` this could be done, but with risk of duplicating info.

Comment: You need CSS Columns. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21404844/949476

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the replies, though. :)

Comment: Depending on the browsers you intend to support, you can do this with flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is not possible to create the layout without using visibility classes of bootstrap.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1846/) using hidden and visible classes to achieve the desired result.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 visible-md-block">5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 visible-md-block">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 hidden-md">
  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12">5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">7</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 visible-md-block">7</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 visible-md-block">8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">9</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">10</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">11</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fullscreen reuslt](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1846/embedded/result/)

The middle div is `hidden` on `tablets` and the respective div in the other column is show using `visible-md-block` classes

Comment: Although I'm not generally fond of duplicated markup I accept this answer as The answer, since it presents a Bootstrap solution, which is what I asked for. :)